# Print multiple time on different lines Python

Tags: python, printing

I have written a code and I want to print multiple time on different lines, I wrote the code below my question is about the last line of code.

```
import math 

# Make an program, ask the user how old he or she is and tell them the year
# they turn 100

name = input("What is your name? ")
age = input("How old are you? ")
random_number = input("Please give a random number between one and ten: ")
age = int(age)
random_number = int(random_number)

year_awnser = 100 - age

year_awnser = int(year_awnser)

print(f"It will take {year_awnser} years until you are 100")


awnser = 2020 + year_awnser

awnser = int(awnser)

print(f"{name} you will be 100 in: {awnser}")

print("\n")

# Print the message above, times given by the random_number.

print(f"{name} you will be 100 in: {awnser}. " * random_number)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ? 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `loop` to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your code, just add the `'\n'` tag:

```
print(f"{name} you will be 100 in: {awnser}. \n" * random_number)
```

I recommend using a loop, because it gives better impression and clarifies the code. The print method has a built in `'\n'` tag in it:

```
for times in range(random_number):
    print(f"{name} you will be 100 in: {awnser}. ")
```